Babies choose their parents before coming to the earth
Babies choose their parents before coming to the earth (or they are being chosen by someone to come to the earth.). I think they could watch the lives of people on earth before choosing them as parents. If they like, they decide to be born.
Babies forget this selection event when they come to the earth. Before earth, they are in a dimension where angels reside.
So, as the time goes by, a kid finds an inter-dimensional gate between angel-world and the earth. Angels start coming to the earth through this gate.
Angels do not grow up. They all look like kids even they have an older age.
I think there was a train scene in the movie.
It was watched on TV. Beginning of 2000s.
Note: It is not "Mr. Nobody".

Similar themes in Made in Heaven but it's from 1987 (or did you mean you only watched it in the 00s?)

@Walt: Not "Made in Heaven". Thanks. It was watched in the 00s and we also think that the movie is made in 00s.

I see. Well, I'm out of guesses. ;) (There's 'Delivering Milo' that almost fits, but not really.)

@Walt: It is "Delivering Milo"! Please post as an answer and I will accept. Thanks :)

Ah, OK. Will do. Glad you found it. :)

Delivering Milo from 2001 with Bridget Fonda and Albert Finney about a guardian angel trying to convince an unborn child to be born. From Wiki:

Elizabeth believes she has gone into labor, but at the hospital, the doctor tells her she was having Braxton Hicks contractions. The reality is that in the world from which babies come, Milo is too scared to leave the comfortable place where he has lived. Since babies must be born in order, no other babies will be born until Milo changes his mind. The people in charge give the job of educating Milo to Elmore, who is in a kind of limbo until he proves he is worthy of Heaven.

